# python dictionary iteration usage error

Tags: python, python-2.7

Ok here is my code:

```
# create variables
direction = ('north', 'south', 'east', 'west', 'down', 'up', 'left',  'right', 'back')
verb = ('go', 'stop', 'kill', 'eat')
stop = ('the', 'in', 'of', 'from', 'at', 'it')
noun = ('door', 'bear', 'princess', 'cabinet')
number = ('0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9')

def scan(word, *words):  # '*words' lets you give a variable number of     arguments to a function
    words = word.split()
    src = { direction : 'direction',
            verb : 'verb',
            stop : 'stop',
            noun : 'noun',
            number : 'number'
            }
    for k, v in src.items():
        if words in k:
            m = src.get(k)   

    print [(m, w) for w in words]

scan("I was going north and south")
```

Problem:

- I am trying to assign the value of the `dic(src)` to `variable m` after running words through `src` to see if one of the content of `words` can be found in `src`.

My Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "koko2.py", line 26, in <module>
    scan("I was going north and south")
  File "koko2.py", line 24, in scan
    print [(m, w) for w in words if w in direction or verb or stop or noun or number]
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'm' referenced before assignment
```

Comment: The `for` loop defines `m` **only** if there is a `k` such that `words in k`. Try to add a `print` inside the `for` to see what is happening and if it matches your expectations.

Comment: What is  `or verb or stop or noun or number` supposed to do?

Comment: Padraic i have removed it as I see its actually a duplicate process in my code.

Comment: What about `*words`? Also what happens if m gets defined multiple times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You logic is all wrong, *words* is a list and a list could never be in your tuple of words so it `m` never gets defines. You need to check if the individual *word* was in the key/tuple. I would use a  *frozenset* of words as keys instead for `O(1)` lookups:

```
def scan(s):  # '*words' lets you give a variable number of     arguments to a function
    words = s.lower().split()
    src = {frozenset(direction): 'direction',
       frozenset(verb): 'verb',
       frozenset(stop): 'stop',
       frozenset(noun): 'noun',
       frozenset(number): 'number'
       }
    for word in words:
        for k, v in src.items():
            if word in k:
                yield word, v
                break


for pair in scan("I was going north and south"):
    print(pair)
```

Which would give you:

```
('north', 'direction')
('south', 'direction')
```

Also if you want to pass a word or words using *args, use *words alone and iterate directly:

```
def scan(*words):  # '*words' lets you give a variable number of     arguments to a function
    src = {frozenset(direction): 'direction',
           frozenset(verb): 'verb',
           frozenset(stop): 'stop',
           frozenset(noun): 'noun',
           frozenset(number): 'number'
           }
    for word in words:
        for k, v in src.items():
            if word in k:
                yield word, v    
                break



for pair in scan("I", "was", "going", "north", "and", "south"):
    print(pair)
```

Comment: Thanks Padraic, I am grateful. The `for words in words:` in your code was it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`if words in k:` is never true so `m` is never defined, hence the error.

You could do something like that:

```
m = ""
for k, v in src.items():
    if words in k:
        m = src.get(k)   

if m:
    print([(m, w) for w in words if w in direction or verb or stop or noun or number])
```

Answer (score 0):

Your design is probably not the best to start, here are my proposals:

```
# frozenset are a better option for these static variables...                                              
direction = ('north', 'south', 'east', 'west', 'down', 'up', 'left',  'right', 'back')
verb = ('go', 'stop', 'kill', 'eat')
stop = ('the', 'in', 'of', 'from', 'at', 'it')
noun = ('door', 'bear', 'princess', 'cabinet')
number = ('0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9')

# Singles string as key are prefered (just my opinion)                                                     
src = {'direction': direction,
       'verb': verb,
       'stop': stop,
       'noun': noun,
       'number': number}


def scan(word, *words):
    words = word.split() if not words else words
    for word in words:
        for k, v in src.items():
            if word in v:
                print((word, k))


def scan_with_ret(word, *words):
    words = word.split() if not words else words
    ret = []
    for word in words:
        for k, v in src.items():
            if word in v:
                ret.append((word, k))
    return ret


def scan_with_ret_oneliner(word, *words):
    words = word.split() if not words else words
    return [(word, k) for word in words for k, v in src.items() if word in v]


print("scan")
scan("I was going north and south")

print("scan_with_ret")
print(scan_with_ret("I was going north and south"))

print("scan_with_ret_oneliner")
print(scan_with_ret_oneliner("I was going north and south"))
```

results:

```
scan ('north', 'direction') ('south', 'direction')
scan_with_ret [('north', 'direction'), ('south', 'direction')]
scan_with_ret_oneliner [('north', 'direction'), ('south', 'direction')]
```

Hope to be helpful here

@Padraic Cunningham: Oups, i didn't see your answer you're right with generator. Thanks for the frozenset explanations, they also preserve data against duplicate.

Comment: nice. Thanks added fuel to my understanding of py-code.